# How to dynamically populate RadioButtonList from SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

We have a RadioButonList with a Yes or No choice, however, we would like the choices to be dynamically populated from the database.

The column name in the database whose values we would like to populate the RadioButtonList is called `IsVetoVote` and it is of datatype `Bit` with 1 for Yes or 0 for No value.

If for instance a user queries the database for a particular proposal to see if this proposal has been voted on, if the answer is yes (or 1), we would like the RadioButtonList Yes box to the checked.
If no (or 0), then the RadioButtonList No box to be checked.

My code is not providing either Yes or No value.

When I run the query portion of the code in SSMS, I get the correct result of either 1 or 0 but the RadioButtonList is not getting checked.

This is my current code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID ="VetoVote" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>    
   
   
Sub LoadData()
        Dim strSQL As String = "Select IsVetoVote from Ballots where choices Like '%' + @vetono + '%'"
        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
        With cmdSQL.Parameters
            .Add(New SqlParameter("@vetono", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = address.Replace("'", "''").Trim())
            End With

        Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

        With rstData.Rows(0)
            ' now set the radio button, we have a true/false column "Active"
            ' in the table. So, if true - set Radbio bt1 index 0 (first choice)
            ' if false, then set RB index 1 = (2nd choice).

         VetoVote.SelectedIndex = Not (.Item("IsVetoVote"))    ' sql returns 1 for true, 0 for false

      End With
     End Sub
     
     Public Function MyrstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable

        Dim rstData As New DataTable

        Using mycon As New SqlConnection(conString)
            Using (cmdSQL)
                cmdSQL.Connection = mycon
                mycon.Open()
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return rstData
    End Function
```

//Checkbox to check if user's billing address is same as mailing address.

```
<td style="width:5%;" class="align-left"><span style="color:darkred;font-weight:600;font-size:14pt;" class="rMyChoice"> Check box if billing address is same as mailing address <img src="Images/hand-arrow.jpg" class="rMyChoice" style="vertical-align:middle !important;" alt="Check the checkbox" /><asp:CheckBox style="height:45px;width:45px;" ID="SameAsMailing" class="rMyChoice" runat="server" /></span></td>
```

Comment: Something just seems a little off with the logic here which makes me thing a little debugging might be in order.  Looks to me you're setting all radio option values to the first and only first result from your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you should not need any loop here.

Say I have a hotel record, and in place of a check box, I decide to use a RB list.

So, if hotel active = true, then set RB first choice.

So, if hotel active = false, then set RB second choice.

So, say this markup:

```
    <h2>Hotel information</h2>
    <div style="float: left" class="iForm">
        <label>HotelName</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Width="280" />
        <br />
        <label>First Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140" />
        <br />
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" f="LastName" Width="140" />
        <br />
        <label>City</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" f="City" Width="140" /><br />
        <label>Prov</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" f="Province" Width="75"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px" class="iForm">
        <label>Description</label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="400" TextMode="MultiLine"
            Height="150px" f="Description"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="VetoVote" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        runat="server" CssClass="rMyChoice" >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Hotel Active" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Hotel Closed for Season" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

And code to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE id = 16"
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

    With rstData.Rows(0)
        txtHotel.Text = .Item("HotelName")
        tFN.Text = .Item("FirstName")
        tLN.Text = .Item("LastName")
        tCity.Text = .Item("City")
        tProvince.Text = .Item("Province")
        txtNotes.Text = .Item("Description")

        ' now set the radio button, we have a true/false column "Active"
        ' in the table. So, if true - set Radbio bt1 index 0 (first choice)
        ' if false, then set RB index 1 = (2nd choice).

        VetoVote.SelectedIndex = Not (.Item("Active"))    ' sql returns 1 for true, 0 for false

    End With

End Sub
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, you not trying to "fill" the RB button, you want to set the first choice, and or the 2nd choice based on a single true/false column.

I note the above, since RB List can be "feed" a datasource.

I might want the user to select ONE hotel out of a list, and so I could have the "value" of the RB list = the database PK id of the Hotel, and then the text part as the Hotel Name.

So, I could say drop into a page this RB list

```
        <h3>Please pick ONE hotel</h3>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBHotels" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            CssClass="rMyChoice">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then this code:

```
Sub LoadRB()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)

    RBHotels.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    RBHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And now we have  list in which you can select ONLY one hotel:

eg this:

[image]

So, we here were thrown for a bit a loop in that you suggesting you going to fill out a RB list with data.

No, you simple want to set the first choice, or 2nd choice based on ONE true/false value from the one record in the database.

Thus, you can set selected index = 0 (first choice), or set selected index = 1 (2nd choice) in your case.

As a FYI, I became VERY tired of typing over and over code to get some data, so the above examples used this helper routine:

```
Public Function MyrstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = mycon
            mycon.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

## edit: RB testing example

So, let's built a 100% new page, with just this markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Set RB Index = 0"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="sET RB index = 1" 
            onclick="Button2_Click"
            />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="VetoVote" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And code behind would be this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    TextBox1.Text = "RB set to 0 index value"

    VetoVote.SelectedIndex = 0

End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    TextBox1.Text = "RB set to 1 index value"

    VetoVote.SelectedIndex = 1

End Sub
```

And we now see this:

[image]

## Edit #2: My css for the RB list

If you have this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID ="VetoVote" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

then we see/get this:

[image]

However, if we add this on that page:

### Edit: updated style sheet - check box removed

```
<style>
    .rMyChoice h1 {
        color: hsla(215, 5%, 10%, 1);
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .rMyChoice section {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }

    section > div {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 0.5rem;
    }

    .rMyChoice input[type=radio] {
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .rMyChoice label {
        display: block;
        background: white;
        border: 2px solid hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 9px;
        height: 30px;
        padding-top: 8px;
    }

    .rMyChoice input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
        background: hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
        color: hsla(215, 0%, 100%, 1);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px hsla(150,5%, 75%, 0.75);
    }

    .rMyChoice input[type="radio"] {
        background: red;
        border-color: red;
    }

    .rMyChoice p {
        font-weight: 900;
    }
</style>
```

then this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="VetoVote" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server"
    CssClass="rMyChoice"
    >
    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

then we get/see this:

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you both for your prompt response.

Albert, this is beautiful code.

Thank you.

A quick follow up if I could sir, with the code that says, "Please pick one hotel", does it mean that the html radiobuttonlist will need to be stripped of the choices?

Comment: As the animated screen gif shows, it starts out with no choice at all. So, since we are feeding the RB list a WHOLE datatable of choices, then it starts out with no choice. When you DO choose a hotel, note how the value = database PK "id" of that table row. So, we could of course right after we "load" up the list of hotel choices THEN set the one existing choice that the user has from say a table. so this would work 100% exactly like a combo box (dropdown list). The list of choices is a table of choices, and choosing one RB item would result in a single PK row id that we save.

Comment: so, if this was a simple asking of the user what hotel they like? yes, to re-edit the data, then right after I loaded up the RB list of hotels, the next line of code should/would set a selected hotel based on say the one user record of some information, including say of what hotel they want to vist. So in this case, (like a combo/dropdown) box, we have a list of choices, but that results in "one" hotel PK id that we would save into the one row in the database. And yes, of course to load + edit + display, then we would have to set the choice from that displayed list of hotels.

Comment: And to 100% answer you question? No, that hotel list only lets the user select ONE value out of the list (kind of the whole idea of a radio button list - only one choice allowed). So no stripping of anything is required here. Just one choice is allowed, and doing so will "highlight" the one choice (like any radio button list works). Of course this example is a bit lame, since we were editing a hotel record. This in practice would be some "people" record, and we display a list of hotels say they picked for their trip to visit , and they can thus only choose one hotel.

Comment: Ok sir, please give me a second to put it all together and will post all back to show you.

I am struggling to follow it all.

Your brain is way too advanced.

The spec is that when a user searches the db with one WHERE predicate, if the vetovote choice is 1 for yes, the Yes box is automatically selected.

Ditto for 0 for No.

Comment: Understood, but I assume we are displaying ONE record result here, and we are using that RB list VERY much like a check box. It only has two choices (on/off or true/false). So, that RB is NOT really a list of choices but ONLY 2 choices to reflect the value of the ONE record you are displaying here. and that true/false value is coming form that one record.

Comment: You are correct.

It is either Yes is checked for a particular record or No.

One of my many  confusions is that we have LoadData() and LoadRB().

Do I need both?

And how do I merge this:
~<h3>Please pick ONE hotel</h3>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBHotels" runat="server"
    DataValueField="ID"
    DataTextField="HotelName"
    CssClass="rMyChoice">
</asp:RadioButtonList>~ with the original HTML RadioButtonList?

I hope to get to where you are one day.

Comment: No, the load RB was to demonstrate that a RB list is NOT only limited to a list of choices, but can function like a combo box (dropdown list). So, a RB list can be a fixed set of choices you type in (like you have - and that is 100% fine). But, often people forget that a RB list can also be feed a whole bunch of choices - choices you don't have to type in by hand. So, no, you don't need or have to care about the 2nd example - it was just a fyi to show that RB list is not limited to hand code fixed choices.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you but what about this?
~        <h3>Please pick ONE hotel</h3>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBHotels" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            CssClass="rMyChoice">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>~

If I have to use it, where does it go?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Example ONLY makes sense if we wanted to "ask" user to select say one of 10 hotels for  planning a trip. If we had 50 hotels then a RB list would be a poor UI choice then right? So, the RB list is only good for a few choices (like your 2 choices), or that example of about 10 choices. Anything more going to take up WAY too much space on the page. So, for 20-50 choices, then a combo box (dropdown list) would be far more appropriate. And more then 50 choices, not even a combo box makes much sense. So where/when to use this? Only if you need to! and you don't appear to need that 2nd example.

Comment: Please hang with me a bit longer. I have updated my code at the top. I ran it with no errors but no boxes are being checked. I tried debugging it but got vetovote.SelectedInded = -1

I know I am missing something.

Comment: You not breaking this down at all here. I mean, the user going to select ONE rocord to edit. Unless you telling me you want to display "many" reocrds on the form. That select statement you added does not make a whole lot of sense, since what is the web page to display? I assume that some how, some place, the user is selected ONE record to display and edit. Now, maybe your goal is to display a grid of "many" records, but you not explained that goal here. Little of this makes sense unless we see some screen shots, or what ONE record you attempting to edit or display here.

Comment: Ok sorry if I didn't explain it well. I think the confusion is that I am selecting just ONE fieldname.

There are actually about 18 fieldnames being displayed on a form based on so many joins and the WHERE predicate that you see there.

That one column, IsVetoVote is the only one I am having problem with and I didn't thint it made sense to post so many lines of code when it is just this one that I am having problem with.

In fact, there is an extension of this that I didn't post that disables a textbox control if veto vote is NO but that works. Only is checking the box if yes, or if no

Comment: Not a problem, as noted, we STILL talking about ONE reocrd. Many fields don't matter. In fact, as I pointed out, we could have used a check box (on or off, true or false). However, we just decided to use a radio button. But, it still a true/false choice - just that we are displaying it in a different way to the user. So, no, don't care about all those other columns. You I presume have some "means" to load up all of the other controls, and our code to setup the RB is also then as we posted. On save, you have get RB selected index and flip from 0 to 1 since we reversed the RB settings

Comment: So, you must have some code that pulls the ONE reocrd, and in that record is the true/false column. So, your code to setup all the text boxes etc. simple means in that code, we also setup the RB choice. We don't need nor want some separate query for JUST the RB list, since as you note, we pulled the row of data, start filling out all the controls, and that includes our one RB button which is a on or off choice. Unless the RB button text is to change for each record - that's a big whopper of a detail missing then. But, yes, we could take say 5-6 Boolean columns, and make 5-6 RB options.

Comment: Thank you sir for your continued assistance. Yes, everything you said is correct . The one part that I *think* is missing is that once we load all the values for the 18 fields, including the RB column called IsVetoVote on the DB,, the RB has to have one box checked whether for Yes or No. In other words, if we load a record for John Doe and he voted Yes, the RB Yes box needs to be checked. If he voted No, the No box needs to be check and that's what I am struggling to get working. If you could help get this to work, that would really appreciated.
Once again, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, that code example was this VetoVote.SelectedIndex = Not (.Item("Active")). So, you can not only get/grab the selected index of the RB, you can also set the value. So, yes, when you load the data, and you start filling out all the controls, you can use that expression, and in place of setting value, or text, we set the index to  0 or 1 (0 = first choice). So, you would use VetoVote.SelectedIndex = Not (.Item("IsVetoVote")) as you have. Only reason why it might not work is if you allow nulls for the true/false column. But yes that code looks correct and should work.

Comment: Well, the records I have tested with so far have either 0 or 1 values.

So, not sure what else needs to be modified in the code to make it work.

Comment: Well, we are missing some issue here. Do the other columns from that ONE row of data work, and controls get their values correctly from the other column values? I would make a test page, and try my edit code (see my edit and new part in above). We dropped that RB into a page with a 2 buttons and a text box. Does that code work for you? I would as a test drop in a text box onto the page, and set the text to the value along with setting the RB - does the text box show the 0 or 1 value correctly?

Comment: Yes sir, once you enter a value into a search box and  hit search, the entire form is populated with data correctly. This is where the RB value is expected to be checked for either Yes or No. It is not getting checked. I have tested it in isolation and have tested it with the rest of the form fields that are populated from same query and no cigars.

Oh I didn't see the change. Let me try it now.

Comment: drop in a test text box RIGHT below the RB in the broken web page. See if the text box shows the value along with the RB that is not working.  So, assign the text box the value like say this: MyTestTextBox.Text = .item("IsVetoVote") and see what the text box shows. I susepect the colum is not a sql server bit column, but is some other type of colum type (like text)

Comment: No the column is a bit datatype. I did make sure of that when I started with the original code I posted here.

Comment: then as noted, drop a textbox right below the RB, and set that text value to the column as per suggestion, and see if that text box sees/gets/shows the correct value then.

Comment: Ok, I think I am beginning to see where the disconnect is.

You are assuming that some action like button click needs to happen in other for the RB box of Yes or No to be checked. 

However, according to our specs, it is supposed to happen automatically. In other words, once you query the db to populate the form fields including the RB, we expect the RB box to be checked automatically for Yes if the db column value is 1 or checked for No if column value is No. What I am getting is that this is not possible? I tried your suggestion but the but it needs to work without clicking a button.

Comment: no I am not. I just stated, drop a plain jane text box RIGHT below the RB, and assign it the the value, say like this:  MyTestTextBox.Text = .item("IsVetoVote"). Does that text box show the value? That test text box is to be dropped right below the existing RB on the page, and the extra line of code is to be dropped right below the line that assigns the RB. Again: does that text box show the value of 0 or 1 then?

Comment: Oh I see. please hang on sir for one sec while I try that.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a dumb question, where will .item("isVetoVote") get its value of either 0 or 1 then since I am dropping the textbox on the button_click method you created with no connection to the DB?

Comment: Huh? You have some code that is to fill out the RB in YOUR code (not the example my code). You (we assume) have some code that is to set the value of the RB. Where is that code? As I stated, in the code right before you made/make that assignment to the RB, put in a extra line of code to set the test text box we are using.  I am not suggesting to use that 2nd new "edit" example code, we are talking about your existing code and page that assigns the value to the RB (not that example I posted). In your code where you assign the RB is where you put this extra test code.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I misread that.

Comment: Ok so when I try that, the RB box does not check the box for Yes or No. However, when I debugged the code, it shows the correct values assigned to the column DB. For instance, when I tested with a record that has column value of 1, it shows it accurately on the debugger just as it does with value of 0. It just does not automatically check the RB box.

Comment: We still not reached the goal and skill set to assign a value to a text box. Until we gain this knowledge, then we can't really write code then, can we? Lets try this again: In your web page, you have a bunch of code that assigns controls on that page. And you have the code that assigns the RB button on that page. we are to add the text text box, and assign that text box the value from the database just like we are doing for the RB. So, again: right after (or right before) the code that assigns the value to the RB, put in the one line of code to assign the value to our test textbox.

Comment: So the textbox is returning the correct values. I don't know if it matters that it is returning False and True as opposed to 0 and 1. 

In other words, some values on the isVetoVote column returns some values as False and True while some are returned as 0 and 1. This should not matter, should it?

Bottom line is yes, it is assigning some values to the textbox

Comment: Ok, so it does not return 0 or 1, but returns true or false. So, this is a great lesson on debugging code! That's why the suggest to place a text box on the form was suggested. this means we have to change Not (.Item("IsVetoVote")) to a if/then statement. so use this ---- if .Item("IsVetoVote") = True then RB.SelectedIndex = 0 ELSE RB.SelectedIndex =1 end if.  So, we can't assume that it returns a 0 or 1, but in fact returns a true/false. So, put in a if / then to set the RB. And then we can remove our test textbox.

Comment: To be fair, my fault, as I assumed we could assign the value to "selectedIndex" of the RB directly. We can't, since it does return a true/false value in VB, while in SQL server that is a "bit" column and considered a VERY small integer value! But, we require a if/then amount  of code and can't assign the column directly to the RB selectedIndex which wants a integer value starting at 0 (for first choice) and so on.

Comment: It is WORKING!!!!!!

WOW, this is the best help I have ever gotten, EVER and I have gotten a lot of help over the cause of of development career. It is the best help because you just didn't write the code and say, "here". You walked me through everything and got me to try things out MYSELF as frustrating as it has been. THANK YOU Albert, thank you very much.

I wish SS has special bonus for your incredible patience.

Thank you very much. Please don't lose this patient and tutoring part of you. Use it for others as I am sure you have been doing. I am truly pleased and impressed.

Comment: Don't worry. we both went down (mostly me!)  the wrong garden path so to speak. This kind of error can result in chewing up a lot of time, but we learn. For example, I'm not going to make that mistake again for some time (we hope). I still do boatloads of vb.net code, and thus I'll remember this when I attempt to assign a true/false value to something that needs 0 or 1 as a integer value. And we also learned some neat bit of code, like how we can fill a RB list with a whole bunch of choices from code. And we have that VERY handy dandy MyRstP bit of code that we can use over and over.

Comment: I have a demo by 10:30am tomorrow and this bit had to work before then and it did because of your awesome expertise and incredible patience.

Many, many thanks.

Comment: See my last edit, I post the css file as to how I made the RB look VERY different with a style sheet. (they become pill shaped if you enter more text - that is the css I used for some of my screen shots.

Comment: You are simply too awesome and very, very generous.

Thank you so, so much.

I have applied the css and it looks great.

Comment: Hi Albert, I have a little problem from the css application.

Because I am using it now, and because I have a checkbox that asks user to check whether the billing address is same as mailing address, the checkbox has disappeared from screen.

I know the reason is because you have it in the styles as display:none; If I change it to block, it messes up the radio button.

Can I modify it to work with my checkbox?

This is not a big deal. I can remove the styles even though they are cool.

I am posting the checkbox bit above just in case you have time to look at it.

Comment: that's a bit of a bug in that css. Change ".rMyChoice input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] " to .rMyChoice input[type=radio]      --- that was a mistake. So, remove the checkbox part from that css. Let me post a updated style for that in a bit.

Comment: Edit, see the new style sheet. The check box stuff is removed - and it should not have been there anyway. Try the new style sheet.

Comment: Everything is working great now. Thank you again